# How do I remove all selected links including ones that are partially selected in CKEDITOR?

Tags: ckeditor

Let's say I currently have this selection:

```
<a href="test.com">te[st</a><p>test1</p><a href="test2.com">te]st2</a>

The [] represents the selection.
```

I would like to expand out the selection to include all `<a>` elements and remove all the `<a>` elements.

I tried expanding out using the `startContainer` and `endContainer`:

```
var selection = editor.getSelection();

var range = selection.getRanges()[0];

range.setStartBefore(range.startContainer.getParent());
range.setEndAfter(range.endContainer.getParent());

var style = new CKEDITOR.style( { element: 'a', type: CKEDITOR.STYLE_INLINE, alwaysRemoveElement: 1 } );
editor.removeStyle( style );
```

But this only removed the stuff in the selection and did not expand the selection.

How can I expand the selection so that it includes whole elements if they are partially selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These lines:

```
range.setStartBefore(range.startContainer.getParent());
range.setEndAfter(range.endContainer.getParent());
```

Will only change the `range` object's properties. And range does not mean selection, it's only a logical representation of delimited piece of content. Read more in the [`CKEDITOR.dom.range`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.range) documentation.

The [`editor.removeStyle()`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-removeStyle) method works on a real selection though and therefore the above range modification did not affect the result. So you either need to select that range using [`range.select()`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.range-method-select) and then use `editor.removeStyle()` or you can use [`style.removeFromRange()`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.style-method-removeFromRange).